# SELECT values from JSONB string in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, jsonb

I have a multiple jsonb strings in a table that where created by a third party app. I want to be able to separate the content into individual rows.
A string looks like this:

```
[[ "Plant","p"],["Animal","gt"],["Lake","gf"],["Mountain","ke"]]
```

I need a Query that creates me the following:

```
Type    | Value
________________
Plant   | p
Animal  |gt
Lake    |gf
Mountain|ke
```

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT e ->> 0 AS type,
       e ->> 1 AS value
FROM jsonb_array_elements(
        '[[ "Plant","p"],["Animal","gt"],["Lake","gf"],["Mountain","ke"]]'::jsonb
     ) AS e;

   type   | value 
----------+-------
 Plant    | p
 Animal   | gt
 Lake     | gf
 Mountain | ke
(4 rows)
```